# Failure when re-rendering _form.html.erb after failing validation in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application manages Business Rules, which apply to one business object. When editing a business rule, I meet an unattended failure.

The _form.html.erb view correctly displays current properties, including the dropdown field :

```
<%= f.collection_select :business_object_id, @business_objects_list, :id, :name  %>
```

Current value is displayed, available values are shown in the drop down list.

When applying a modification (not related to this drop down) which fails validation, Rails tries to render _form.html.erb, but raises an error due to missing @business_objects_list:

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

@business_objects_list is created in the private section of the business rules controller:

```
    # Retrieve business objects list
    def set_business_objects_list
      if action_name == 'edit'
        my_business_area = @business_rule.business_process.business_flow.business_area_id
      else
        my_business_area = BusinessProcess.find(params[:business_process_id]).business_flow.business_area_id
      end
      @business_objects_list = BusinessObject.where("business_area_id = ?", my_business_area)
end
```

The set_business_objects_list function is called at the top of the controller:

```
 before_action :set_business_objects_list, only: [:new, :edit]
```

**EDIT:** Controller actions

```
  # GET /business_rules/1/edit
  def edit
    ### Retrieved by Callback function
  end

  # PUT /business_rules/1
  # PUT /business_rules/1.json
  def update
    ### Retrieved by Callback function
    @business_rule.updated_by = current_user.user_name

    respond_to do |format|
      if @business_rule.update_attributes(business_rule_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @business_rule, notice: 'Business rule was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @business_rule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Can you please help find out what's wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with action where you are handling the render when the validation failed

Comment: Try changing `before_action :set_business_objects_list, only: [:new, :edit]` to `before_action :set_business_objects_list, only: [:new, :edit, :update]`

Comment: Great! You are right!  This has to be initialized also for update action! Thanks a lot Pavan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

You need to make `@business_objects_list` available to the `update` action as well because `render action: "edit"` just loads the `edit.html.erb`. So the scope of `@business_objects_list` is lost

**Solution:**

Just add the `update` action to the list of actions to the `before_action :set_business_objects_list`

```
before_action :set_business_objects_list, only: [:new, :edit, :update]
```